# To show split view from full screen modal view

Tags: ios, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller, modalviewcontroller

I have a screen in my application with split view. and from that I am able to show to next screen which is a modal view with modal view presentation style full screen. Now I want to come back from full screen modal view and show the split view again.

If I write:

```
    [self.navigationController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Then only one part of split view controller is coming in full screen not the splited view.
How can I get split view controller from full screen modal view controller?

Comment: try [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

Comment: @S.P.  No it is giving same output. It dismisses modal view but coms to the part from where I have presented the modal view, not the full split view. Thanks.